# stdext::hash_map unclear hash function

Tags: c++, hashmap

```
#include <iostream>
#include <hash_map>

using namespace stdext;
using namespace std;

class CompareStdString
{
public:
bool operator ()(const string & str1, const string & str2) const
    {
        return str1.compare(str2) < 0;
    }
};
int main()
{
    hash_map<string, int, hash_compare<string, CompareStdString> > Map;
    Map.insert(make_pair("one", 1));
    Map.insert(make_pair("two", 2));
    Map.insert(make_pair("three", 3));
    Map.insert(make_pair("four", 4));
    Map.insert(make_pair("five", 5));
    hash_map<string, int, hash_compare<string, CompareStdString> > :: iterator i;
    for (i = Map.begin(); i != Map.end(); ++i)
    {
        i -> first; // they are ordered as three, five, two, four, one
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use hash_map to keep std::string as a key. But when i insert the next pair order is confused. Why order is do not match to insert order ? how should i get the order one two three four five ??

Comment: Which raises the question why you don't use `std::unordered_map` ...

Comment: I think `std::map<int, std::string>` would order the values like you want without any additional work.

Comment: @andre `std::map` doesn't use insertion order either (at least not by default and it isn't so easy to get a comparator that does).

Comment: We use MSVS 2008 yet...

Comment: It looks like you want Boost.MultiIndex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why order is do not match to insert order?

That's because a `stdext::hash_map` (and the platform-independent standard library version `std::unordered_map` from C++11) doesn't maintain/guarantee any reasonable order of its elements, not even insertion order. That's because it is a hashed container, with the individual elements' position based on their hash value *and* the size of the container. So you won't be able to maintain a reasonable order for your data with such a container.

What you can use to keep your elements in a guaranteed order is a good old `std::map`. But this also doesn't order elements by insertion order, but by the order induced by the comparison predicate (which can be confugured to respect insertion time, but that would be quite unintuitive and not that easy at all).

For anything else you won't get around rolling your own (or search for other libraries, don't know if boost has something like that). For example add all elements to a linear `std::vector`/`std::list` for insertion order iteration and maintain an additional `std::(unordered_)map` pointing into that vector/list for O(1)/O(log n) retrieval if neccessary.

Comment: Thank you for your ansewers! This is really helped to understand the thing.

Comment: @user2560991: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Be sure to vote up and 'accept' the response if it answers your question.